# The dependence of entropy on temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, physical-chemistry

I am wondering why the entropy will increase faster for a gas (when compared to a liquid/solid) when temperature increases? Is it because the heat capacity for a gas is lower than solids and liquids?
I am confused because a graph showing S vs. Tf/Ti would show substances with a higher heat capacity to have a larger slope.

Answer (score 0):

Both entropy and heat capacity are related to an infinitesimal heat transfer $dQ$:

$$dQ=TdS$$
$$dQ=CdT$$

If we equate the two right-hand sides, we get:

$$TdS=CdT$$

or, in other words:

$$\frac{dS}{dT}=\frac{C}{T}$$

So, for two substances at the same temperature with different heat capacities, entropy will increase *faster* as the temperature is raised for the substance with *higher* heat capacity.

Comment: Oh I see! Does this mean that gas has a higher heat capacity than solid and liquid? I thought that solids/liquids have a higher heat capacity?